# Is it possible to repair UEFI that won't boot Windows 10 using Ubuntu 21 on a dual boot hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair, mbr

I have Windows 10, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and Ubuntu Mate all on the same HDD drive on my HP Envy m7-n100 laptop.

This has been working fine for years. When there was a major update to either of the Ubuntu 18 distros, they would switch position in the GNU GRUB boot order.

Yesterday, I got a Windows 10 update and now Windows 10 won't boot, but Ubuntu will. When I check the BIOS, there is an exclamation mark after the option to boot from the hard drive. A note says that means

> boot capability is disabled.

In UEFI, it is called "OS boot manager". And in Legacy Mode, it is called "notebook hard drive"; both are potentially actuated, but both have the exclamation symbol.

I thought that maybe I could repair the UEFI using a Parted Magic disc from about 4-6 years ago, but luckily I read that it doesn't support UEFI before I took any action.

I have a Win 10 repair disc I created, but it won't boot; funny because the Parted Magic disc booted. I have an Acronis backup on WD Passport external drive, but it doesn't boot. I also have an Acronis boot USB jump drive that won't boot.

Soooo... I am thinking that maybe there might be a way to repair the UEFI from Ubuntu; or is it the MBR?
I am not a coder, but I can follow a recipe using the terminal.

Comment: Boot-Repair really only fixes Linux and its main fix is a reinstall of grub. But its report shows details which we need to know if possible to fix. Can you not boot directly in UEFI mode from UEFI menu. Often Windows updates turn fast start up back on, and then you cannot boot Windows from grub. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Usually the exclamation mark means that it's unable to detect the boot drive or executable, what you need to investigate is what did windows exactly do when it had this major update, and for the possibility of fixing it from ubuntu I believe its possible, try mounting the windows boot partition and run `sudo os-prober` and see if it can detect MS Windows.

Comment: Ubuntu has products that use the *year* format (since 2016) but they are different systems to those using the *year.month* format.  They are different products, use different packages (*year.month* default to *deb* but can also use *snap*, *year* are *snap* only, *year* have longer supported lives with no changes of apps when you upgrade release as no need with *snap* etc) so you're mixing up two different products is confusing.  There also is no Ubuntu 21 as *snap* only releases come out even years only.

Comment: This could be a secure boot problem.

Comment: What happens if you try again to boot into Windows while pressing the F8 key?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if there is a friend whose windows uefi is damaged in dual boot, I make a bootable fdd uefi mode using rufus with the help of vbox on linux with usb extended pack.
After finishing packing I use cmd on bootable usb installation windows cmd with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

```
sfc /scannow
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /ScanOs
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

etc or recovery maintenance.